# summarize data.table .SD, while sorting by one of .SDcols

Tags: r, data.table

How do I calculate a cumulative sum of .SD columns while sorting by the first of .SDcols (without summing this first column)

For a toy example:

```
require(data.table)
dt<-data.table(expand.grid(dow = 1:5, person = c("alice", "bob")))
setcolorder(dt, c("person", "dow"))
dt[, `:=`(current1 = runif(nrow(dt)), current2 = runif(nrow(dt)))]
```

The data prior to summation:

```
    person dow current1 current2
1:  alice   1    0.266   0.9447
2:  alice   2    0.372   0.6608
3:  alice   3    0.573   0.6291
4:    bob   1    0.908   0.0618
5:    bob   2    0.202   0.2060
6:    bob   3    0.898   0.1766
```

`dt[order(dow), lapply(.SD, cumsum), by = c("person")]` yields the desired cumulative sums of `current1` and `current2`:

```
    person dow current1 current2
1:  alice   1    0.266   0.9447
2:  alice   3    0.638   1.6055
3:  alice   6    1.210   2.2346
4:    bob   1    0.908   0.0618
5:    bob   3    1.110   0.2678
6:    bob   6    2.008   0.4443
```

but also, undesirably, sums `dow`.

`dt[order(dow), lapply(.SD, cumsum), by = c("person"), .SDcols = c("current1", "current2")]` drops the `dow` col. altogher.

The desired output should have the dow column ordered but not summed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can specify the columns of interest in `.SDcols` and update the other columns by assignment operator `:=` to assign the output values in place

```
dt[order(dow), c('current1', 'current2') := lapply(.SD, cumsum),
      by = .(person), .SDcols = current1:current2]
```

NOTE: The function used is `cumsum`, so it will generate the same number of rows as in the original dataset

Comment: that works. but is there a way to scale it to referencing cols e.g., `cols_to_sum <- grep("current", names(dt), value = T); dt[order(dow), cols_to_sum := lapply(.SD, cumsum), by = .(person), .SDcols = cols_to_sum]` won't work as it would generate a column named cols_to_sum.

Comment: @dzeltzer. Just wrap with parens i.e. `cols_tosum` should be `(cols_to_sum) :=`